# Is there a way in React Navigation to send parameters from one tab to another?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a simple component (`BottomTabNavigator`) that has two tabs. One of them is a pretty simple settings screen that tracks stores the current settings in its state. I now want to pass this settings back to the other tab so that it can adjust according to the settings. (Something equivalent to `this.props.navigation.navigate('RouteOtherTab', { settings: this.state.settings })` but having a button with onPress and instead passing the Params just when they change the Tab)

Maybe it is pretty stupid to implement settings like this. If so please tell what the standard is so that I can adjust (I am pretty new to React Native and React Navigation)

Comment: As already mentioned you should be using a global state management system, something like redux or mobx,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to pass the parameters back and forth (which I know is a pain in React Navigation), why not make use of a [store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobx) that will keep track of the app's settings?

This way you don't have to keep passing the settings parameters around. You probably want to use the settings in other pages as well in the future, so being able to access it from the store would save you a lot of time and effort.